# Count nested items conditionally in an aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to count status occurrences in a MongoDB collection from two places. Given document like the one below, I would like to count `status` from the root of the document if there are no statues under `statuses` in one aggregation, but haven't been able to determine how to do this conditionally.

```
{
    "id": "some unique id",
    "groupId": "some many to one id mapping",
    ...
    "status": "ACCEPTED",
    "statuses": [{
        "personId": "some id",
        "status": "ACCEPTED"
    }, {
    "personId": "some other person",
        "status": "REMOVED"
    }]
}
```

Right now I have an aggregation to count all `statuses.status` but haven't been able to get accurate counts if there are no statues. This may require a model change, but ideally I would think there is a method to do this conditionally.

My aggregation pipeline looks like this:

```
final List<DBObject> statusPipeline = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                        match,
                        Aggregation.group("groupId", "statuses.personId", "statuses.status"),
                        Aggregation.unwind("status"),
                        Aggregation.group("$groupId", "status").count().as("total")
                )
                .toPipeline(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT).stream()
                .map(BasicDBObject::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

An example of a document that I want to include in the aggregate:

```
{
        "id": "some unique id",
        "groupId": "some many to one id mapping",
        ...
        "status": "UNPROVISIONED",
        "statuses": []
}
```

The final counts for these two documents should be UNPROVISIONED: 1, ACCEPTED: 1, and REMOVED: 1. Or something like:

```
[{
   "groupId": "A",
   "UNPROVISIONED": 1
}, {
   "groupId": "A",
   "ACCEPTED": 1
}, {
   "groupId": "A",
   "REMOVED": 1,
}]
```

Comment: So the first sample document in your question should _not_ be included in the results? Or are you saying that that first document should increment the count for `ACCEPTED` values twice and `REMOVED` a single time? (and the other sample document should increment `UNPROVISIONED` once?

Comment: In the first example, `ACCEPTED` and `REMOVED` should be counted once, in the latter example `UNPROVISIONED` should be counted once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the grouping/counting logic, but perhaps this provides the output you are looking for.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "statuses": {
        "$cond": [
          { // if there are statuses.status ...
            "$gt": [{"$size": "$statuses.status"}, 0]
          },
          // ... use those
          "$statuses.status",
          // ... otherwise use status
          ["$status"]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$statuses"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "groupId": "$groupId",
        "status": "$statuses"
      },
      "count": {"$count": {}}
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rxdJk72etkg).